# Getting typescript errors when building Nestjs Dockerfile

Tags: docker, nestjs

I have a Dockerfile for a Nestjs project, I start the container with docker-compose. But I am getting some typescript errors during the build stage.

Have been hours and I still not able to find a solution. Anyone has idea how to tackle this? Thanks a lot! Let me know if I have to provide more information

[image]

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine as base

LABEL maintainer="dev@crowdlinker.com"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./ 


FROM base as dev

RUN npm install

RUN npm link webpack

COPY .eslintrc.js nest-cli.json tsconfig.json tsconfig.build.json ./

COPY .env /usr/src/app/.env

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev", "--preserveWatchOutput" ]

FROM base as prod

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

And the compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  backend:
    # container_name: edudb_backend
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      target: prod
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=production
      - APP_PORT=8000
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app/src
      - ./test:/usr/src/app/test
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - default
  mysql:
    # container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      # - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=edu_db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - edudb_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - default

volumes:
  edudb_mysql_data:

networks:
  default:
    name: edudb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

You can't only install production dependencies and expect building (a dev process that requires depDependencies) to work. Most of the time, `@types/` packages are saved as `devDependencies` and are used by Typescript to ensure the types are correct.

Generally speaking, for running the application you should only need production `dependencies`, and building the application should happen in an earlier stage of a multi-stage dockerfile, like in your `dev` stage. Then you have `prod` copy the `dist` from `dev` and install only the production dependencies so you can `node dist/main` without any typescript dependencies